# jquery - mouseover() triggering when mouse on div's previous(default) position

Tags: jquery

I have this javascript:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.button').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });

    $('.button').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

and this css:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    height: 120px;
    width: 240px;

    background-color: #6699ff;
    border: 10px groove gray;
    border-radius: 15px;

    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The mouseover event trigger both when mouse hovers over current div position and 'default' div position, and I have no idea why.

edit:
It seems that the reason for this problem is the "display: table-cell;". When display is set to this, the problem happens both with "mouseenter()" method and with ":hover" method. I use the table-cell display to center text inside the div, so any solutions would be welcomed.

Comment: Why jQuery and not CSS for the opacity animation? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc3vtbs3/)

Comment: I tried this a an exercise in using jquery. How would you use CSS to accomplish this?

Comment: Check the link in my comment ;)

Comment: I see... interesting to see that the problem with mouseenter() doesn't occur with :hover . Thank you :)